# How to pass a token environment variable into a provider module?

Tags: terraform

I have made a Terraform script that can successfully spin up 2 DigitalOcean droplets as nodes and install a Kubernetes master on one and a worker on the other.

For this, it uses a bash shell environment variable that is defined as:

```
export DO_ACCESS_TOKEN="..."
export TF_VAR_DO_ACCESS_TOKEN=$DO_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It can then be used in the script:

```
provider "digitalocean" {
  version = "~> 1.0"
  token   = "${var.DO_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
}
```

Now, having all these files in one directory, is getting a bit messy. So I'm trying to implement this as modules.

I'm thus having a `provider` module offering access to my DigitalOcean account, a `droplet` module spinning up a droplet with a given name, a `Kubernetes master` module and a `Kubernetes worker` module.

I can run the `terraform init` command.

But when running the `terraform plan` command, it asks me for the provider token (which it rightfully did not do before I implemented modules):

```
$ terraform plan
provider.digitalocean.token
  The token key for API operations.

  Enter a value:
```

It seems that it cannot find the token defined in the bash shell environment.

I have the following modules:

```
.
├── digitalocean
│   ├── droplet
│   │   ├── create-ssh-key-certificate.sh
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── vars.tf
│   └── provider
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── vars.tf
└── kubernetes
    ├── master
    │   ├── configure-cluster.sh
    │   ├── configure-user.sh
    │   ├── create-namespace.sh
    │   ├── create-role-binding-deployment-manager.yml
    │   ├── create-role-deployment-manager.yml
    │   ├── kubernetes-bootstrap.sh
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── outputs.tf
    │   └── vars.tf
    └── worker
        ├── kubernetes-bootstrap.sh
        ├── main.tf
        ├── outputs.tf
        └── vars.tf
```

In my project directory, I have a `vars.tf` file:

```
$ cat vars.tf 
variable "DO_ACCESS_TOKEN" {}
variable "SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" {}
variable "SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" {}
variable "SSH_FINGERPRINT" {}
```

and I have a `provider.tf` file:

```
$ cat provider.tf 
module "digitalocean" {
  source          = "/home/stephane/dev/terraform/modules/digitalocean/provider"
  DO_ACCESS_TOKEN = "${var.DO_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
}
```

And it calls the `digitalocean provider` module defined as:

```
$ cat digitalocean/provider/vars.tf 
variable "DO_ACCESS_TOKEN" {}

$ cat digitalocean/provider/main.tf 
provider "digitalocean" {
  version = "~> 1.0"
  token   = "${var.DO_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
}
```

UPDATE: The provided solution led me to organize my project like:

```
.
├── env
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── backend.tf -> /home/stephane/dev/terraform/utils/backend.tf
│   │   ├── digital-ocean.tf -> /home/stephane/dev/terraform/providers/digital-ocean.tf
│   │   ├── kubernetes-master.tf -> /home/stephane/dev/terraform/stacks/kubernetes-master.tf
│   │   ├── kubernetes-worker-1.tf -> /home/stephane/dev/terraform/stacks/kubernetes-worker-1.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf -> /home/stephane/dev/terraform/stacks/outputs.tf
│   │   ├── terraform.tfplan
│   │   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   │   ├── terraform.tfstate.backup
│   │   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   │   └── vars.tf -> /home/stephane/dev/terraform/utils/vars.tf
│   ├── production
│   └── staging
└── README.md
```

With a custom library of providers, stacks and modules, layered like:

```
.
├── modules
│   ├── digitalocean
│   │   └── droplet
│   │       ├── main.tf
│   │       ├── outputs.tf
│   │       ├── scripts
│   │       │   └── create-ssh-key-and-csr.sh
│   │       └── vars.tf
│   └── kubernetes
│       ├── master
│       │   ├── main.tf
│       │   ├── outputs.tf
│       │   ├── scripts
│       │   │   ├── configure-cluster.sh
│       │   │   ├── configure-user.sh
│       │   │   ├── create-namespace.sh
│       │   │   ├── create-role-binding-deployment-manager.yml
│       │   │   ├── create-role-deployment-manager.yml
│       │   │   ├── kubernetes-bootstrap.sh
│       │   │   └── sign-ssh-csr.sh
│       │   └── vars.tf
│       └── worker
│           ├── main.tf
│           ├── outputs.tf
│           ├── scripts
│           │   └── kubernetes-bootstrap.sh -> /home/stephane/dev/terraform/modules/kubernetes/master/scripts/kubernetes-bootstrap.sh
│           └── vars.tf
├── providers
│   └── digital-ocean.tf
├── stacks
│   ├── kubernetes-master.tf
│   ├── kubernetes-worker-1.tf
│   └── outputs.tf
└── utils
    ├── backend.tf
    └── vars.tf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option you have here is to just not define the provider at all and just use the [`DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/index.html#token) environment variable as mentioned in the Digital Ocean provider docs.

This will always use the latest version of the Digital Ocean provider but otherwise will be functionally the same as what you're currently doing.

However, if you did want to define the provider block so that you can specify the version of the provider used or also take this opportunity to define a partial state configuration or set the required Terraform version then you just need to make sure that the provider defining files are in the same directory you are applying or in a sourced module (if you're doing partial state configuration then they must be in the directory, not in a module as state configuration happens before module fetching).

I normally achieve this by simply symlinking my provider file everywhere that I want to apply my Terraform code (so everywhere that isn't just a module).

As an example you might have a directory structure that looks something like this:

```
.
├── modules
│   └── kubernetes
│       ├── master
│       │   ├── main.tf
│       │   ├── output.tf
│       │   └── variables.tf
│       └── worker
│           ├── main.tf
│           ├── output.tf
│           └── variables.tf
├── production
│   ├── digital-ocean.tf -> ../providers/digital-ocean.tf
│   ├── kubernetes-master.tf -> ../stacks/kubernetes-master.tf
│   ├── kubernetes-worker.tf -> ../stacks/kubernetes-worker.tf
│   └── terraform.tfvars
├── providers
│   └── digital-ocean.tf
├── stacks
│   ├── kubernetes-master.tf
│   └── kubernetes-worker.tf
└── staging
    ├── digital-ocean.tf -> ../providers/digital-ocean.tf
    ├── kubernetes-master.tf -> ../stacks/kubernetes-master.tf
    ├── kubernetes-worker.tf -> ../stacks/kubernetes-worker.tf
    └── terraform.tfvars
```

This layout has 2 "locations" where you would perform Terraform actions (eg `plan`/`apply`): staging and production (given as an example of keeping things as similar as possible with slight variations between environments). These directories contain only symlinked files other than the `terraform.tfvars` file which allows you to vary only a few constrained things, keeping your staging and production environments the same.

The provider file that is symlinked would contain any provider specific configuration (in the case of AWS this would normally include the region that things should be created in, with Digital Ocean this is probably just clamping the version of the provider that should be used) but could also contain a partial Terraform state configuration to minimise what configuration you need to pass when running `terraform init` or even just setting the required Terraform version. An example might look something like this:

```
provider "digitalocean" {
  version = "~> 1.0"
}

terraform {
  required_version = "=0.11.10"

  backend "s3" {
    region         = "eu-west-1"
    encrypt        = true
    kms_key_id     = "alias/terraform-state"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-locks"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution not only solved my issue, but it also provided me with guidelines on how to layer my project. On top of it, I discovered what CNC means and what CN Cloud does. Pretty cool !

Comment: The key part for me was when you wrote `state configuration happens before module fetching`.